# Hide div when clicking on link text

Tags: html, toggle, hide, visibility

I have a fullscreen slider in background and a text logo on it for my wordpress homepage.

I would like to hide and show this slider by clicking on my text logo.

The function I use works actually great but I have to click twice on the text logo to make it run.

```
<div id="conteneur">
    <div id="fullscreen-slider" class="royalSlider rsDefault">
    <img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/perron_01.jpg" />
    <img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/perron_01.jpg" />
    </div>

    <header>
        <div id="logo">
            <a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('fullscreen-slider');">Adequat</a>
        </div>
```

And the script :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggle_visibility(id) {
   var e = document.getElementById(id);
   if(e.style.display == 'block')
      e.style.display = 'none';
   else
      e.style.display = 'block';
}</script>
```

I think the browser search for the href="#", and only once he finds it, my script goes well.

Thank you for your help and I am sorry but I am a beginner and my website is not yet online.

Adrien Quélet

Comment: Are you using jQuery or just straight up javascript?

Comment: just a script but I am thinkin on trying a jQuery thing of course if you have an idea !

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery (which I recommend) [Here is a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ptosL2z9/) example.

The script is very much simpler to use/maintain.

**JQUERY**

```
$('#logo').click(function(event) {
    $('#logo a').toggle();
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

You would need to modify your css and such to fit your needs, but this should get you going.

Comment: Thank you guys,

Actually, this is a bit more complicated because I want the slideshow to be hidden by clicking on text logo and shown by clicking again on it.

The other thing is that I don't want this slideshow to appear on the others pages because it is actually on my "header.php" because I want it to be in the main div content.

Here is the exact thing I am trying to do :

http://www.johnpawson.com

Comment: But as I was saying, I'd like to totally remove the class after clicking. Because my slide is on the header.php. I don't know if it is clear sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Do it the other way around:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggle_visibility(id) {
        var e = document.getElementById(id);
        if(e.style.display == 'none')
            e.style.display = 'block';
        else
            e.style.display = 'none';
    }
</script>
```